# dnsmasq circular loop error

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq, pfsense

I know I am missing a configuration somewhere, but I just can't find it. I have two routers, A is upstream of B, both running dnsmasq.
A has domain A.com
B has domain B.A.com

A has in dnsmasq.conf

```
server=/B.A.com/IPofB
```

B, if it can't find the correct record, asks A. This works great EXCEPT when it comes to a record that doesn't exist. So say B is asked for noexist.B.A.com. It can't find it, so it asks A, what is noexists.B.A.com. A can't find it, but has the server rule, so it asks B, which doesn't find it so it......

As you can see, it loops back and forth. I know I have a setting wrong somewhere, or more likely missing a setting, but can't seam to find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding a record that doesn't let the system forward any of the subdomain that do not exist to router B.

```
server=/B.A.com/!
```